# JIRA REST API call from PHP cURL wont work with PUT/DELETE methods

Tags: php, json, rest, api, curl

I'm trying to call the API of JIRA via PHP's cURL but I can't make the PUT/DELETE methods to work. cURL cli from linux work. 
**Example:**

```
curl -u user:pass -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"fields": {"summary": "[Test] Testing REST API!"}}' http://jirahost.com/rest/api/2/issue/testIssue
```

My PHP code:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);                                  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $jirauser . ":" . $jirapass);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $jirahost . "issue/testIssue");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data)
print_r(curl_exec($curl));
```

My `cURL` options are right, 'casue `GET/POST` requests work.

Comment: `"Doesn't work"` -- Please elaborate. What error do you get?

Comment: No errors. `curl_exec` just returns `NULL` and the issue is not updated
Also keep in mind that I don't have access to the JIRA logs.

Comment: What happens if you try: `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true)`? This prints debug to STDERR; you can also have it write to a log file if you prefer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757071/php-debugging-curl

Comment: Thank a million. I am using slim framework and I forgot to add the `$args` so I was passing to the wrong URL.